# Getting the full path to the assets folder

Tags: java, android

I am using a method that require a full path for a file as a String, I have the data stored in the assets folder of my project and I cannot seem to get to it via file:///android-assets/my-file, I think it because the method wants a FULL path. is there a solution to this or should I try a different storage option?

Answer (score 0):

**For URI**
Its file:///android_assets/{Relative Path}. Note the 'underscore' between the words android and assets, not 'hyphen'.

However there's no absolute path for asset files, but you can get an Input Stream of the file like this

```
    getResources().getAssets().open("fileName")
```

Comment: Is there a way to get the input stream as a `File`?

Comment: You can always store the file temporarily in the cache directory and get its path from there.